# CoordinatorLayout.Behavior - blocksInteractionBelow() not working, getScrimOpacity() not overlaps button

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I was so inspired by this feature of coordinator layout ([link to post](https://medium.com/google-developers/intercepting-everything-with-coordinatorlayout-behaviors-8c6adc140c26)):

> There’s another, more heavy handed touch interception though: blocking
>   all interactions whatsoever. Just return true in
>   blocksInteractionBelow() and that’s it. Of course, you probably want
>   to have some visual signal that interactions are blocked (lest they
>   think the app is completely broken) — that’s why the default
>   functionality of blocksInteractionBelow() actually relies on the value
>   of getScrimOpacity() — return a non-zero value here will both paint an
>   overlay color over the View (of color getScrimColor(), defaulting to
>   black) and disable touch interactions all in one swoop. Handy.

I have an activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.a_main);
    }

    public void click(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Go", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Go"
        android:onClick="click"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:background="#409"
        app:layout_behavior=".B"
        android:elevation="16dp"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and behavior

```
public class B extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<View> {

    public B(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public float getScrimOpacity(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child) {
        return .8f;
    }

    @Override
    public int getScrimColor(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child) {
        return Color.RED;
    }
}
```

But unfortunately, as a result - click on button still works and button is not overlaping by scrim color.

[image]

Hope somebody knows what am i doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @Stallion If i understand right, with no params it locates views as a FrameLayout, so this is what i want. You can suggest what i should add and i will try

Comment: @Stallion i use Coordinator, not Constraint layout

Comment: sorry , my bad... I miunderstood as coordinator layout